# Solr Reindex issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, sunspot-rails, reindex

I am using the sunspot gem for searching functionality in my project. 
However, re-indexing in Solr is causing problems. When I re-index Solr on my local machine, the data is re-indexed properly but it not giving me the proper results when executing searches.

But with the same codebase and db setup on the server, the search returns the proper result.

I cannot find a solution as to why this is happening. Is there any limitation for re-indexing data?

Comment: Could you post some specific steps that illustrate the issue? If so perhaps one of us could reproduce it.

Comment: RAILS_ENV=development bundle exec rake sunspot:reindex                         bellow is the command which i used for the re-index.